# Where do I put session_start function?

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

I'm fairly new to PHP and I'm trying to work out the best place in my current scenario to place the `session_start()` function.

I'm currently making website and the first page to load is `index.php` which requires `db.php` to connect to a MySQL database, and only contains an html form for logging in and pushes an error message when the details are invalid.

When the user enters the username & password, the data is passed to `checklogin.php`, where prepared statements are used and if the data matches then `$_SESSION['username']` is called and the user is redirected to `portal.php`. (If there is no match, it redirects to `index.html` with an error message now visible.)

My question is, should `session_start()` be placed at the beginning of `index.php` (code mainly in html, uses php only to `require 'db.php';`, to connect to the database and to push the error message if credentials don't match).

Or, should I use it at the beginning of `checklogin.php` (where `$_SESSION['data']` is used for the first time)?

Answer (score 1):

> The session_start() function must be the very first thing in your document. Before any HTML tags.

Every page that will use the session information on the website must be identified by the `session_start()` function. This initiates a session on each PHP page. The session_start function must be the first thing sent to the browser or it won't work properly. It must precede any HTML tags. Usually, the best place to position it is right after the `<?php` tag. It must be on every page you intend to use.

Comment: `must be the very first thing in your document`. It's not true, you only need to start sessions when reading or writing sessions....